# how to extract the certain variables estimate from regression analysis

Tags: r, purrr, metafor

I ran a meta-regression analysis in the `metafor` package using the following code:

```r
output5_MR = map(metrics4,
                 #magrittr::extract(!. %in% c("Soil NPK availability", "Nutrient use efficiency")),
                 function(i) metadata1 %>%
                   dplyr::filter(measurement_n==i) %>%
                   rma.mv(lnrr, v, random = ~ 1 | publication_title / unique_id, mods = ~ duration_exp + temp_group + soil_texture + country, 
method = "REML", data=.))
```

`metrics4` contains 9 dependent variables. When I ran the model, I got the results for all effect modifiers (which are given with the `mods` function) together with intercept. I would like to extract the value of the estimate `b` and standard error `se` of a certain effect modifier, let's say `Biochar_app_rate`. I tried the following code

```r
output5_MR_b <- map_dbl(output5_MR, 
                        function(x) as.numeric(x[["b"]]))

output5_MR_se <- map_dbl(output5_MR$Biochar_app_rate, 
                         function(x) as.numeric(x[["se"]]))
```

But these codes extract `se` and `b` for all the effect modifiers. Does anyone know how to create a code for extracting `b` and `se` of certain effect modifiers?

Here is a sample dataset:

```r
unique_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
publication_title <- c("publication1", "publication1", "publication1", "publication2", "publication2", "publication2", 
                       "publication2", "publication2", "publication2", "publication2")
publication_title <- c(0.04, 0.01, 0.42, 0.34, -0.24, -0.12, 0.30, 0.12, -0.80, 0.03)
v <- c(0.005272691, 0.011742537, 0.169538779, 0.085044762, 0.083513861, 0.056932582, 0.043557358, 
       0.045750691, 0.001520993, 0.001417840)
measurement_n <- c("Soil total NPK", "Soil mineral nitrogen", "Soil mineral nitrogen", "Plant nutrient level",
                   "Soil total NPK", "Plant nutrient leve", "Plant nutrient level", "Soil total NPK", 
                   "Plant nutrient level","Plant nutrient level")
duration_exp <- c(150, 150, 150, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90)
temp_group <- c("Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High")
soil_texture <- c("sandy clay loam", "sandy clay loam", "sandy clay loam", "Sandy loam", "Sandy loam",
                  "Sandy loam", "Sandy loam", "Sandy loam", "Sandy loam", "Sandy loam") 

country <- c("Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China")          

metadata1 <- data.frame(unique_id, publication_title, publication_title, v, measurement_n, duration_exp,
                        temp_group,  soil_texture, country)
```

Comment: I can't run/reproduce your code when I set `metrics4 <- metadata1` and try it: I get `Cannot find the object/variable ('lnrr') specified for the 'yi' argument`. I would suggest `library(broom); tidy(output5_MR)`, then use appropriate `filter()` specifications based on the value of `term` to get what you want ...

Comment: I think I kind of solved it, using the following code ```output5_MR_table = map(output5_MR, function(x) tibble("name" = rownames(x[["b"]]), "b" = as.numeric(x[["b"]]), "se" = x[["se"]]) %>%  filter(str_detect(name, "intrcpt|Biochar_app_rate")) )```

Comment: If you solved your problem, and you think the answer is generally useful, feel free to post an answer your own question (don't update your question to include the answer, please - questions and answers are separate).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using the `filter` function of `dplyr` as follows

```
output5_MR_table = map(output5_MR,
                       function(x) tibble("name" = rownames(x[["b"]]),
                                          "b" = as.numeric(x[["b"]]),
                                          "se" = x[["se"]]) %>%
                         filter(str_detect(name, "intrcpt|Biochar_app_rate")) )
```

Here I extracted the `estimate` and `se` of a specific variable (Biochar_app_rate) of the regression analysis. Please, note that I used `map` function of `purrr` and it returns the results in a list.